# angular ng-repeat with condition

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

How do you do something like this in angular with ng-repeat?
I'll be using the example from the documentation which inits an array with 2 friends, what if I wanted to only do a repeat for all friends that are 26 and older?

```
    <!doctype html>
<html ng-app>
<head>
<script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.0.6/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div ng-init="friends = [{name:'John', age:25}, {name:'Mary', age:28}]">
I have {{friends.length}} friends. They are:
<ul>
<li ng-repeat="friend in friends">
[{{$index + 1}}] {{friend.name}} who is {{friend.age}} years old.
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Create a custom filter.

HTML:

```
<html ng-app="someApp">
```

and

```
<li ng-repeat="friend in friends | age">
```

JS:

```
var someApp=angular.module('someApp', []);

someApp.filter('age', function() {
    return function(input, uppercase) {
        var out = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
            if(input[i].age >= 26){
                out.push(input[i]);
            }
        }
        return out;
    }
});
```

Comment: thx, I found it allready it's indeed a filter :) I'm still learning angular.js and tbh it's a pretty big framework with a lot of bells and whistles to which I'm not accustomed yet :)

Comment: I too am going through the same road. Its just that I happened to know the answer on this occasion :D

Answer (score 15):

you can use "ng-show="friend.age >=26"  with the ng-repeat="friend in friends". it will only show the friends who's age is  greater than and equal to 26.

```
<body>
<div ng-init="friends = [{name:'John', age:25}, {name:'Mary', age:28}]">
      I have {{friends.length}} friends. They are:
     <ul>
         <li ng-repeat="friend in friends" ng-show="friend.age >=26">
           [{{$index + 1}}] {{friend.name}} who is {{friend.age}} years old.
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: This works, but could cause a lot of unneeded markup, especially if you want to show all other age groups the same way.

Answer (score 7):

Here is the working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vinodlouis/am9Ec/1/)

```
   $scope.call = function(a){

    if (a.age > 26)
        return true;
    else
        return false;

}
```

Comment: I like the filter idea better... this is strange.

Comment: For me this is good, as you don't need to add the filter at app level, this will keep the filter function at controller scope.

Answer (score 4):

I used a filter in `ng-repeat` to:

```
<div ng-repeat="product in products | filter:{ colour: by_colour }">
```

Comment: <div ng-repeat="product in products | filter:{ colour: by_colour }">

Comment: You should edit you answer instead of leaving a comment.

Comment: @Ivan I guess OP didn't understand how to format code, and the HTML was not showing. I fixed it.