# Angular JS - ng-repeat and loop conditions

Tags: javascript, angularjs, loops, for-loop, conditional-statements

Hey i  have this piece of code:

```
<div ng-repeat="i in values">
{{i}}
</div>
```

It works but i would like to put extra conditions inside the loop something like:

```
<div ng-repeat="i in values">
{{i}}
if(i !== 0){
<div></div>
}
</div>
```

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Use `ng-if` (or `ng-show`):

```
<div ng-repeat="i in values">
   <div ng-if="i !== 0"></div>
</div>
```

Attached to the element, this will decide whether to display it or not.

Documentation for [ng-if can be found here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngIf).

However, if you want to only do something if you are looping the first or last item, you can use `$first` and `$last` properties of `ng-repeat` as well.  These are [documented with ng-repeat](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngRepeat).  And can be used like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="i in values">
   <div ng-if="$first"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: ng-if is a better solution than ng-show because ng-if modifies the DOM. ng-show only shows/hides the element.

Comment: @RaviH yes, that is why the example uses ng-if.  But, they are both valid solutions based on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @DavinTryon hey thank you , do you know man how can i put an incremental var in this same loop ? :P i would like to show a div inside loop only if increment%3 === 0 for example but i can't find out how :(

Comment: @sbaaaang  There is one built in to ng-repeat: `$index`.  You've also got `$odd` and `$even` to do things like alternate rows.

Comment: yeah, that should do it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21869283/when-to-favor-ng-if-vs-ng-show-ng-hide

Comment: I think better to use a filter, because i hope (didn't check) that $index will have real element index (like filtered array index). 

If we use ng-if (that actually simplest solution that can came into mind), we will have problems with $index, because there would be hidden elements that would considered by $index as well.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18056241/angular-ng-repeat-with-condition

Answer (score 9):

Use the `ng-if` [statement](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angIf)

```
<div ng-repeat="i in values">
   {{i}}
   <div ng-if="i !== 0"></div>
</div>
```