# AngularJs: How to re-attach a handler after using ng-if?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I've looked at this question where it says:

[When to favor ng-if vs. ng-show/ng-hide?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21869283/when-to-favor-ng-if-vs-ng-show-ng-hide)

*"For example, if you bound a click handler to one of child elements, when ng-if evaluates to true, that element will be removed from DOM and your click handler will not work any more, even after ng-if later evaluates to true and displays the element. You will need to reattach the handler."*

What does it mean to reattach the handler though? For this example here, the function bound to ng-click actually works even when I remove and add the element.

```
<tr ng-if="!useUserLoginTemplate" class="showRowAnimation">

          <td>Template</td>
          <td>
              <input type="file" file-model="loginTemplateFile">  
              <span class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="uploadLoginTemplateFile()">Upload</span> 
          </td>

</tr>
```

I cannot access the file using $scope.loginTemplateFile like I do with the versions without ng-if though.

File-model directive linking function:

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        var model = $parse(attrs.fileModel);
        var modelSetter = model.assign;

        element.bind('change', function(){
            scope.$apply(function(){
                modelSetter(scope, element[0].files[0]);
            });
        });
 }
```

What is going on here?

Comment: Have you tried using a scope on your directive instead of parsing the attribute? Say like `scope: { templateFile: '=fileModel' }` and then setting `scope.templateFile`? (I don't know really why `$parse` doesn't work, but it might be worth a try)

Answer (score 4):

In theory (not always true, but generally), 'reattaching the handler' applies to handlers that are being generated in imperative code, buried somewhere in a controller or another directive or something. Using a nice declarative directive like `ng-click` shouldn't be a problem, because those handlers are going to be re-attached for you by Angular whenever that template is rendered. In my [subsequent answer to the SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23505047/800457) you cite, I talked about how imperative handlers like that are *generally* a bad idea, unless they're conditional to some model data that persists between views.

To your more specific question about why you can't access `$scope.loginTemplateFile`, it would help to have a Fiddle to debug. One question: why not just use ng-model to declare your model binding and keep that cleaner? You can access ng-model information a bit more declaratively then, by using the `require:` property to inject it, as in [this article](http://suhairhassan.com/2013/05/01/getting-started-with-angularjs-directive.html#.U2lc061dUWZ). (My initial suspicion would be that the form you're using is resulting in the `loginTemplateFile` property getting written onto multiple scopes somehow, particularly if the template we're seeing is getting rendered into the DOM based on an ng-repeat or something.)

Comment: A pity that this was not accepted as the answer, in order to make things clearer to others who are searching. I have just read the referenced question and was about tho ask exactly this question (until I discovered that this existed). I would have accepted this as the answer. OP?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access the file using `$scope.loginTemplateFile` because your directive name itself is `file-model` and you are calling the directive name as attribute in your `link` function.

To access the parent scope data and when you are restricting the directive to be of 'Attribute' type then please refer the below updated code snippet.

```
<input type="file" file-model attrName="loginTemplateFile">
```

Where `file-model` is your directive and `attrName` is the attribute name which can be referenced by the directive's link function.
I am modifying the `link` function to use the updated attribute name

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        var model = $parse(attrs.attrName);
        var modelSetter = model.assign;

        element.bind('change', function(){
            scope.$apply(function(){
                modelSetter(scope, element[0].files[0]);
            });
        });
 }
```

Please refer the [angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) on how to create the directives..