# AngularJS - Show a div if date is within last six months

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-show, ng-hide

I have a simple ng-repeat that displays a list of names and icons:

```
<div ng-repeat="data in MyData">
    <p>Name: {{ data.Name }}</p>
    <span class="warning-sign"></span>
</div>
```

How can i modify this so that i display a list of all names, but icons only for the last 6 months?

I've tried:

```
$scope.Today= new Date();
$scope.SixMonths = new Date();
$scope.SixMonths .setDate($scope.SixMonths.getMonth() + 6);
```

Which i could incorporate an `ng-show` on my `<span>`

Answer (score 2):

In your controller

```
var now = new Date();
$scope.sixMonthAgo = new Date().setMonth(now.getMonth() - 6);
```

In your template

```
<div ng-repeat="data in MyData">
    <p>Name: {{ data.Name }}</p>
    <span class="warning-sign" ng-if="data.checkingDate > sixMonthAgo"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Where has data.checkingDate come from??

Comment: In your case it doesn't realy matter. More information you can get from [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21869283/when-to-favor-ng-if-vs-ng-show-ng-hide).
**data.checkingDate** is just a simple... You have some sort of collection (**MyData**), if you want to display icons only for last 6 month, you have to have some field in your object, which cares about date (creation date, registraion, etc.). In my example I called it `checkingDate`.