# Add CSS class using angular

Tags: angularjs

I have the following on Angular controller scope model:

```
$scope.model = {
  subscriber: { email: '', name: '' },
  notice: { text: '', type: '' }
}
```

I need to display a P tag whenever notice.text is not empty and add a CSS class equal to notice.type. So I have:

```
<p class="notice" data-ng-bind="model.notice.text" data-ng-if="model.notice.text != ''"></p>
```

P tag has always the class "notice". But I need to add the class contained in $scope.model.type if it is defined.

How can I do this?

Side question:
Is there a better way to show / hide the P tag instead of using data-ng-if?

Comment: You could consider `ng-show` instead of `ng-if`, but make sure to read about the difference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21869283/when-to-favor-ng-if-vs-ng-show-ng-hide

Answer (score 2):

You can use [ngClass](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) directive

> The ngClass directive allows you to dynamically set CSS classes on an HTML element by databinding an expression that represents all classes to be added.

*Code*

```
ng-class="model.notice.text != '' ? model.notice.type : ''"
```

Comment: I was considering that ... so i can have class="notice" and for the type use ng-class? I tought I would need ng-class for both so that was my problem ...