# Best way to show/hide a part based on permission level - Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-routing

I have an AngularJS Single Page Application where there are lot of HTML blocks which I show to users based on their permission levels.

The user permission is determined by `service` calls and a value is set based on permission.

`$scope.permission = 'admin'`

I can use `ng-hide/show` directives to hide those blocks based on permission. But I am worried about security. By changing the css `display` property those who are not authorized can also view those blocks.

The other option is `ng-if`, which I am using currently. But I would like to know whether I should do the same with `routing`, which is more secure, I believe. I can use `ui.router` angular module to acheive this. But what is the right way?

Should I use `ng-hide/show`, `ng-if` or `routing`?

Expecting some good thoughts.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21869283/when-to-favor-ng-if-vs-ng-show-ng-hide

Answer (score 8):

> You should create a directive for such purpose:

```
app.directive('checkPermissions', ['PermissionsServices', function(PermissionsServices) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {

            if (attrs.permissions != '') {
                var hasPermission = PermissionsServices.hasAccess(attrs.checkPermissions);

                if (false == hasPermission) {
                    elem.remove();
                }
            } else {
                elem.remove();
            }
        }
    };
}]);
```

> HTML Section

```
<a href="http://some_url" check-permissions="state1.name1" >Some URL</a>
<a ui-sref="state2.name2" check-permissions="state2.name2">State 2</a>
<button ng-click="state3.name" check-permissions="state3.name3">State 3</button>
```

> PermissionsServices.hasAccess() function in the PermissionsServices service will check if the User has access to particular state of your application. You might be using Angular Router or UI Router for handling states. I am using UI router so my code in the function is below. This function will just return true or false.

```
PermissionsServices.hasAccess = function(stateName) {
        var hasAccess                   = false;


        //Some complex checking algorithm based on your requirement
        hasAccess = true

        return hasAccess;
};
```

Hope that helps!!

Comment: Great example and super complete. Just what I needed. I'll implement it in ES6. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Basically ng-if add/removes the element to the DOM where ad ng-show/ng-hide just hides the element with css.

routing is also a viable option but this way you will have multiple partials for different users. if you just want to hide some stuff from some users I would go with ng-if

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Currently I am using ng-if.

Answer (score 4):

To handle authorization from a route perspective, we can build some custom extensions to the angular routing infrastructure. The routes can be defined as

```
$routeProvider.when('/admin', {
    templateUrl: 'admin.html',
    controller: 'AdminController',
    roles: ['admin']  //custom extension
});
$routeProvider.when('/home', {
    templateUrl: 'home.html',
    controller: 'HomeController',
    roles: ['admin', 'user'] //custom extension
})
```

Here the role array define who has access to the route.

To enforce it we can use the `routeChangeStart` event to verify rights. This is an excerpt from my book which highlights how to enforce roles

```
angular.module('app').run(function ($rootScope, $location,
SessionContext) {
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function (event, next) {
        if (next.roles && !SessionContext.authenticated) {
            $location.path('/login'); //needs to login
        }
        if (next.roles && SessionContext.authenticated && !SessionContext.isInRole(next.roles)) {
            $location.path('/unauthorized'); //un-authorized
        }
    });
});
```

The `SessionContext` service tracks the loggedin user roles.

Answer (score 0):

As replied by Coder John, the User will always be able to hack this. Even you can make it harder using directive or ngif condition, but since they have access to the full source code, it can always be modified Client side.

As suggestion written above the element itself remove if we use directive or ngif approach. Is there way to remove java script function too which written to handle Click event of button? Since i am putting directive or ngif condition on button element.

Best regards.