# How to use a control statement (if statement) in a nested ng-repeat directive?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have the following code in my HTML View:

```html
<div ng-repeat='shop in shops'>
  <ul ng-repeat='item in items'>
    <li>
      <!-- {{Show items of the particular shop in here}} -->
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The `items` is a JSON Object. Every item has a `shop_id` that has to be used to do the sorting.

According to the documentation, I understand that I cannot use the `if` control statement in an Angular Expression to achieve what I the sort. How else can I use the control statement.

I tried this, but it obviously failed because we cannot return a `continue`.

```js
//var resources.items and resources.shops are JSON objects output from a database

//This file is app.js

$scope.itemName = function(itemIndex, shopIndex) {
  for (var i = 0; i < resources.items.length; i++) {
    if (resources.items[itemIndex].shop_id == resources.shops[shopIndex].id)
      return resources.items[itemIndex].name;
  };
  return continue;
}
```

And, this in the view:

```html
<div class="tab-content" ng-repeat='provider in providers'>
  <ul ng-repeat='item in items'>
    <li>{{itemName($index, $parent)}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I'm a beginner in Angular. Please help out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [ngIf](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf) directive:

```
<div ng-repeat='shop in shops'>
  <ul ng-repeat='item in items'>
    <li ng-if="item.shop_id === shop.id">
      <!-- {{Show items of the particular shop in here}} -->
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh.. I didn't knew about the ngIf. I will try it out now. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Yup no problem. Also read about [ngShow](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow) and the [differences between ngIf](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21869283/when-to-favor-ng-if-vs-ng-show-ng-hide)

Comment: It works. Thanks! Is there any other way I could do it?

Comment: ngShow would probably change the CSS of the element, not actually remove it. Right? ngIf is lot better then. Thanks!

Comment: Exactly, where as ngIf removes the element from the DOM