# When to use ng-if vs ng-show/ng-hide?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ng-if, angularjs-ng-show

I understand that ng-show and ng-hide affect the class set on an element and that ng-if controls whether an element is rendered as part of the DOM

**Are there any examples on choosing ng-if over ng-show/ng-hide or vice-versa?**

Comment: Just look at this.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21869283/when-to-favor-ng-if-vs-ng-show-ng-hide

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19177732/what-is-the-difference-between-ng-if-and-ng-show-ng-hide

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've already summed it up in your question.  If you want to show and hide the DOM depending on a condition, use `ng-show`.  This works well for DOM transitions between workflows, tabs, sections, etc.

```
<div ng-show="vm.tab == 'products'"></div>
```

If you only want to conditionally render the DOM if a condition occurs, use `ng-if`.  This is particularly useful for permissions where you aren't interested in exposing any more DOM than necessary.

```
<button ng-if="vm.data.allowSubmit" ng-click="vm.submit()" />
```

Answer (score 1):

If there is some information what you dont want to show to user any how.
You want that user cant see it anyhow even after editing `DOM` from `inspect element` then use `ng-if` otherwise use `ng-show`.

ng-show renders the `dom` but if condition is false then element `display` will be `invisible`.

```
`ng-if` renders the `dom` only if condition is true
```

There are situations when you are force to use `ng-show`
`ex:` Consider you are using any jquery plugin which runs on `dom ready` on any element. If element is getting rendered later when ng-if gets true then jquery will not work. In this case you will be need to use `ng-show`