# Filter separate variable in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I have some code that looks like this:

```
<input ng-model="search" type="text">

<td ng-repeat="key in targets">
    {{ display_names[key] }}
</td>
```

---

To be more clear:

- `targets` is a variable containing not-human readable ids such as `key012`
- `display_names` is an object which has keys like: `key012: "USA"`

---

I would like to filter the `display_names` value from the search? Looking at the angularjs docs, I know I can filter `key`, but I haven't figured out how to filter `display_names`

---

## Example

Here's a full example:

```js
 var TS = angular.module('myapp', []);

 TS.controller('test', function($scope) {
   $scope.targets = ["id_1", "id_2"];
   $scope.display_names = {
     "id_1": "USA",
     "id_2": "Mexico"
   };
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="test">
  <input ng-model="search" placeholder="Search...">

  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="key in targets">{{display_names[key]}}</li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

Comment: what do you mean by `is a global`? Can only iterate angular scope variables

Comment: @charlietfl nope. Did not mean is a global :p, fixed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<td ng-repeat="key in targets">
    <span ng-if="display_names[key].indexOf(search) > -1">{{ display_names[key] }}</span>
</td>
```

use `ng-if`, or you could also use `ng-show`. Differences [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21869283/when-to-favor-ng-if-vs-ng-show-ng-hide)

This way, as you write in search (which should be in `$scope.search`) angular will refresh the `ng-repeat` values to show

If  you want to search it case-insensitive, you could use toLowerCase() function before using indexOf

```
display_names[key].toLowerCase().indexOf(search) > -1
```

Comment: `ng-if="display_names[key].indexOf(search) > -1"` ==> `ng-if="key.indexOf(search) > -1"`

Comment: but OP wants to filter values, not keys

Comment: Is there anyway to do this case-insensitive?

Comment: as I understand, he wants to filtering i.e. "USA". Since he got all the keys in targets, he wants to access `display_names[key]` => "USa", "MExico" and so on.. As I understand, he does not want to filter by "id_01". @Vihan can you clarify ?

Comment: you can add toLowerCase() to `display_names[key]` before using `indexOf`

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a filter `|` in the html because you don't have the value you want to filter against in the array you are iterating over. Instead you can use `ng-if` to show/hide the elements based on the search. Something like:

```
<div ng-repeat="key in targets" ng-if="!search || !!display_names[key].match(search)">
  {{ display_names[key] }}
</div>
```

The `!!` boolean cast is done because otherwise a new Regex object will be returned for the match which triggers a digest cycle which will return another new object and so on.

You also probably want to iterate over `<tr>` rather than `<td>`, and you need a `<table>` element for these elements to be allowed.

Example: http://plnkr.co/edit/qrpLKD9x4IBXowpIgnrf?p=preview

---

You could also write a custom filter for this, but it is a lot more work:

```
.filter('displayNames' function () {
  return function (key, names, search) {
    return !search || !!names[key].match(search);
  };
});
```

And use it like `key in targets | displayNames:display_names:search`