# How to update ng-if in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am writing an Angular application where the navbar is supposed to be different depending on whether or not the user is logged in. I have an angular view that looks like this:

```
<!-- Auth -->
<nav ng-if="isAuthenticated()" class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      ...
    </div>
</nav>

<!-- No auth -->
<nav ng-if="!isAuthenticated()" class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      ...
    </div>
</nav>

<!-- Content -->
<div ng-view></div>
```

With this controller:

```
$scope.isAuthenticated = function() {
    return $auth.isAuthenticated();
};
```

When the page initially loads, this works perfectly; however, after the user logs in, the navigation view doesn't change, even though isAuthenticated() now returns a different value. I read about ng-if creating it's own scope, and tried to do this:

```
<!-- Auth -->
<nav ng-if="nav.auth" class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        ...
    </div>
</nav>

<!-- No auth -->
<nav ng-if="!nav.auth" class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        ...
    </div>
</nav>

<!-- Content -->
<div ng-view></div>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.nav = {
    auth: false
};

$scope.isAuthenticated = function() {
    return $auth.isAuthenticated();
};

$scope.$watch($scope.isAuthenticated(), function(value) {
    console.log("Authentication changed; status: " + value);
    $scope.nav.auth = value;
});
```

But this doesn't seem to work either. Is there a way I can update ng-if so that the `isAuthenticated` function is checked continuously?

Comment: How are you updating the authentication state returned by $auth? Are you just using Angular's $http, $timeout etc. services or are you using some other HTTP library or directly using `setTimeout`? It could be just that you're performing an operation that doesn't trigger Angular's digest cycle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this exact case I would use `ng-show` and `ng-hide` because: [When to favor ng-if vs. ng-show/ng-hide?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21869283/when-to-favor-ng-if-vs-ng-show-ng-hide)

```
$scope.isAuth = false;

function isAuthenticated() {
    $scope.isAuth = checkAuthStatus();

    function checkAuthStatus() {
        return $auth.isAuthenticated();
    }
}
```

Then in the markup:

```
<!-- Auth -->
<nav ng-show="isAuth" class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      ...
    </div>
</nav>

<!-- No auth -->
<nav ng-hide="isAuth" class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      ...
    </div>
</nav>
```

You could also use **[ng-class](https://scotch.io/tutorials/the-many-ways-to-use-ngclass)** as well, as it's slightly better performance wise in some cases.

`<nav ng-class="{ 'display-on' : isAuth }"`

Comment: a global ***authentication service*** would be a better option rather than creating `controller` variables

Answer (score 0):

You need not to update ng-if rather you need to call isAuthenticated() function again so that it will update the value say from true to false or something like that

Answer (score 0):

On the controller create a scope variable and use the same in the ng-class, no need to use watch functions.

```
 $scope.isAuthenticated = function() {
    $scope.navclass = 'notAuthenticated';
    if ($auth.isAuthenticated()) {
        $scope.navclass='Authenticated';
    } 
};
```