# Angular ng-if element has class

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a directive that i only want active should an element have a certain class. for this i have attempted the following:

```
<feedback-analytics ng-if="$('#analyticTab').hasClass('active')"></feedback-analytics>
```

However when the class of the element changes the element is not displayed.

Has anyone done something similar and made it work?

Comment: If you want to show/hide your element, you should use "ng-show" or "ng-hide" instead, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21869283/when-to-favor-ng-if-vs-ng-show-ng-hide

Comment: @Aliz i need the directive to be rendered completely from new thats why i use ng-if - its a hack for a bug in the Chartjs lib

Comment: You could fire an event when the class appear on your element "analyticTab" (with a directive and $watch), and in the controller of your "feedback-analytics" if you catch the event you re-render your directive

Comment: Why isn't jQuery tagged or mentioned in the title of the question? This is not purely an Angular question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something else:

In controller add a scope.$watch that watches over: `$('#analyticTab').hasClass('active')`. Anytime when the value is changed, it will call this watch.

Then create a scope variable of boolean type that will be false or true, depends on above condition.

In view change your code to this: `<feedback-analytics ng-show="yourBooleanVariable"></feedback-analytics>`

Comment: This would work 100% but im not using controllers and $scope as they will partly disappear in Angular 2 and using them is no longer best pratice :s

Comment: I see. Well I will think about something and if I can find something I will tell you :)