# ng-if or ng-show to hide and show a DIV?

Tags: angularjs

The code I am working on has this:

```
<div ng-if="cos.connectMessage" style="text-align: center;" class="ng-scope">
    Unable to establish a connection to the localhost server for 5 minutes.</div>
```

Is there any advantage to using ng-show or ng-if to control the visibility of this message?

Comment: yes, if the `connectMessage` value changes in the model it will automatically update the view and vice versa

Comment: @Katana - but isn't that the same with ng-if and ng-show?

Comment: definitely yes, the only difference is the purpose and usage of that directive but the two-way data binding concept is still there

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When to favor ng-if vs. ng-show/ng-hide?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21869283/when-to-favor-ng-if-vs-ng-show-ng-hide)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**ng-show**

The ngShow directive shows or hides the given HTML element based on the expression provided to the ngShow attribute. The element is shown or hidden by removing or adding the .ng-hide CSS class onto the element. ([reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow))

**ng-if**

The ngIf directive removes or recreates a portion of the DOM tree based on an {expression}. If the expression assigned to ngIf evaluates to a false value then the element is removed from the DOM, otherwise a clone of the element is reinserted into the DOM. ([reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf))

Note: When ng-if removes the element it also removes the associated scope for that element and it get recreated when condition turns true.

Advantage

I prefer the use of ng-if specifically when number of watchers bound inside the element is more as it would completely destroy the scope so making the UI a bit faster. But for small elements or elements containing less watchers does cost overhead of removing scope and recreating it.

Comment: you just copied and pasted :-( What I would like to know is if there is any advantage between using one or the other for the purpose i'm using. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can refer this for your solution, already lot of things asked in that 
[what is the difference between ng-if and ng-show/ng-hide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19177732/what-is-the-difference-between-ng-if-and-ng-show-ng-hide?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `ng-if="false"` then html content under `ng-if` will not includ in your html page, but if you are using `ng-hide="true"` or `ng-show="false"` then html part includ in your html page but it will only in hidden mode.