# Delete with ng-if?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ng-if

I'm listing stories on an angular html page as follows:

```
<li class="myStories" ng-repeat="story in authors.currentAuthor.stories | orderBy: '-_id'">
       <!--  <span ng-if="checked" class="animate-if"> -->
        Title: {{ story.title }}<br>
        Genre: {{ story.genre }}
  <a ui-sref-active="active" ui-sref="storyEdit({ id: story._id })" 
       id="{{ story._id }}">Edit Story
  </a> 
</li>
```

The Angular docs state that "ng-if directive remove DOM element if expression return false" so I wondered whether it is possible/legitimate to delete an item using ng-if?

Answer (score 1):

The item is only removed from DOM. It's still in your data representation. For visual things it is legitimate and most of the time better than ng-show see: [When to favor ng-if vs. ng-show/ng-hide?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21869283/when-to-favor-ng-if-vs-ng-show-ng-hide)

Comment: Thanks trollr, that helps - so if I understand correctly I could use it on the current (authorProfile) page to remove it from the list there but it would still appear elsewhere (eg an 'all stories' page)

Comment: Could you define `data representation` please? If you mean the scope that the `ngIf` creates then it is deleted and recreated right?

Comment: The data are still in authors.currentAuthor.stories, if we use the example above from Andy83. ng-if removes and creates the DOM element. That's right.