# using ng-if inside ng-repeat toshow a button in a table

Tags: angularjs

[characters table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GAff7.png)

hello guyz in the image above am trying to show a button if the character isDead = true but the button doesn't display. here is my code:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Age</th>
                    <th>isDead</th>
                    <th>Resurrect</th>
                    <th>Increase Age</th>
                    <th>Details</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-hide="products.length">
                    <td colspan="3" class="text-center">No Data</td>
                </tr>
                <tr ng-repeat="item in products">
                    <td>{{item.name}}</td>
                    <td>{{item.age}}</td>
                    <td>{{item.isDead}}</td>
                    <td ng-if="item.isDead == 'true' ">
                        <button class="btn btn-success">Resurrect</button>
                    </td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Convert this

```
<td ng-if="item.isDead == 'true' ">
```

to this

```
<td ng-if="item.isDead">
```

N:B: using `ng-if` in `td` will break your html.

Answer (score 1):

I am not clear on what the value of item.isDead is, but if it is a boolean and not a text representation of one, then you should simply use:

```
ng-if="item.isDead"
```

This is because this is evaluating for a true/false, and item.isDead already provides that.

Also, in regard to the HTML this will output, you should change to:

```
<td>
    <button class="btn btn-success" ng-if="item.isDead">Resurrect</button>
</td>
```

Otherwise, on items where item.isDead is true, you will end up with mis-matched columns as there will be one less cell on these rows.

Comment: Thanks for the info

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to use ng-show like this:

```
<td ng-show="item.isDead">
```

Or better for the design use the ng-show on the Button element.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21869283/when-to-favor-ng-if-vs-ng-show-ng-hide

some short summary why/when to use ng-if and when to use ng-show or ng-hide