# Do ng-hide and ng-show actually load the element and hide it, or does it only load on ng-show?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

If it is the first, is it an effective way of programming, given that the elements may be 10 mb images or something? And what would be a better way?

Comment: Better way would be to use `ng-if` instead of `ng-show`, so that DOM will get added only when it is needed to be there

Comment: Check: [When to favor ng-if vs. ng-show/ng-hide?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21869283/when-to-favor-ng-if-vs-ng-show-ng-hide)

Answer (score 0):

ng-show/hide simple changes the display style, so the element is still loaded into the DOM regardless of the result.

You can use `ng-if` to determine if an element should be loaded to the DOM or not. [Documentation here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf)