# AngularJS validation issue

Tags: angularjs, razor

I try to validate a form `productForm` by using AngularJS directives, so I try:

```
<form id="productForm" name="productForm" novalidate>
     <div style="width: 100%; margin-top: 15px; float: right; ">
                <label style="width:103px;float:right" class="col-sm-2" for="ProductName">ProductName: </label>

                <div style="float:right" class="col-sm-5">
                    <input ng-required="true" class="form-control" style="float:right" type="text" id="ProductName" name="ProductName" ng-model="modal.ProductName" value="" />
                </div>
                <div style="float:right" class="col-md-7" >
                    <span class="help-block" ng-if="productForm.ProductName.$error.required && productForm.ProductName.$dirty && productForm.ProductName.$touched "> Name is Must</span>
                </div>

    </div>
    <button class="btn" style="background-color: #ed9c28;" type="button" ng-click="Save()" ng-disabled="productForm.$invalid">Save</button>
</form>
```

In this way the problem is: when user touch the `ProductName` and then it lost focus, the required message didn't show( it just was shown when user type in the input and then clear whole text from the input, but I want to show error message when the input is empty), i try to use `productForm.ProductName.$touched` in `ng-if` of error message for do it, but it doesn't work, How can I do it?

Comment: To understand what's going on do this: `<pre ng-bind="productForm.ProductName | json"></pre>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would omit the check for $dirty and instead check for `$invalid` and `$touced`:

```
ng-if="productForm.ProductName.$invalid &&  productForm.ProductName.$touched"
```

Comment: It isn't the answer. `ngShow` and `ngIf` both works for this case (even if `ngShow` shouldn't be used in any case).

Comment: @developer033 Why souldnt ngShow used in any case? The solution is to omit the dirty check and the note, that I would use ng-show was just a hint. But maybe you can convince me...

Comment: Well, `ngShow` is considered a bad practice. `ngIf` is the recommended, but you can use `ngShow`. What I'm pointing here that his problem isn't with `ngIf`.

Comment: Thats right, the problem isn't related with ngIF and its probably save to use there so I will remove the hint. However, please tell us why ngShow is bad practice? I more often see ppl prefer to use ngShow over ngIf....

Comment: You can check the accepted answer [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21869283/when-to-favor-ng-if-vs-ng-show-ng-hide). Besides `ngIf` seems to have a better performance, you can manipulate classes easier and so on..

Comment: @MartinBrandl thanks for your answering, it works, can u explain me why my way doesn't work? and what is the problem. thank u very much

Comment: ng-dirty class tells you that the form has been modified which it doesn't if you just focus it and leave it...