# Toggle angular attribute on ng-click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, toggle

I have a Google Map, with markers that I want to toggle on and off.

```
<marker id='{{marker.id}}   'visible="{{ condition ? 'true' : 'false'}}">
</marker>
```

And I made a button for toggling it off

```
<button ng-click="condition = false" ng-init="condition = true">
     Toggle visibility
</button>
```

How do I make it switch between toggling the condition true/false, on the same click?

Or maybe using a toggle functionality.

Comment: Use condition = !condition as the value for the ng-click attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<marker id='{{marker.id}}   ng-if="condition"></marker>
<button ng-click="condition = !condition" ng-init="condition = true">Toggle isibility</button>
```

Use ng-if over ng-show, this is another discussion 
[When to favor ng-if vs. ng-show/ng-hide?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21869283/when-to-favor-ng-if-vs-ng-show-ng-hide)

Answer (score 1):

just use ng-show and invert condition variable on button click

```
<marker id='{{marker.id}}   ng-if="condition"></marker>
<button ng-click="condition = !condition" ng-init="condition = true">Toggle visibility</button>
```