# Button in table angular

Tags: angularjs, button, html-table

What I need to do is show button in table, but when "name" is "True" the button should not show. Only when "name" is "False: the button should be in the table.

**My Json**

```
[
        "name" : "False",
        "date" : "22/02/2015"
    },
    {
        "name" : "False",
        "date" : "18/03/2013"
    },
    {
        "name" : "True",
        "date" : "12/06/2012"
    }]
```

**My table**

```
<tr ng-repeat="name in names">
   <td>{{name.name}}</td>
   <td>{{name.date}}</td>
   <td><button ng-model="post">POST</button></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `ng-if` to `show` and `hide` button

```
<tr ng-repeat="name in names">
    <td>{{name.name}}</td>
    <td>{{name.date}}</td>
    <td>
        <button ng-if="name.name === 'False'">POST</button>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

**you can use ng-if or ng-show or ng-hide**

```
<tr ng-repeat="name in names">
<td>{{name.name}}</td>
<td>{{name.date}}</td>
<td>
    <button ng-if="!name.name">POST</button>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Go througth this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/21870119/6554634 to get better idea about `ng-if`, `ng-show` and `ng-hide`.

And there is mistake in your data, there is no opening brace for first object. This is silly but causes loss if we didn't notice.

```
[
    {
        "name" : "False",
        "date" : "22/02/2015"
    },
    {
        "name" : "False",
        "date" : "18/03/2013"
    },
    {
        "name" : "True",
        "date" : "12/06/2012"
    }
]
```

I prefer `ng-if` as it removes element from DOM if not necessary.

```
<tr ng-repeat="name in names">
   <td>{{name.name}}</td>
   <td>{{name.date}}</td>
   <td><button ng-model="post" ng-if="name.name==='False'">POST</button></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

- Your JSON is invalid
- Use ng-show to show the button when name is True.

**Working demo :**

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.names = [{
        "name" : "False",
        "date" : "22/02/2015"
    },
    {
        "name" : "False",
        "date" : "18/03/2013"
    },
    {
        "name" : "True",
        "date" : "12/06/2012"
    }];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<table>
<tr ng-repeat="name in names">
   <td>{{name.name}}</td>
   <td>{{name.date}}</td>
   <td><button ng-model="post" ng-show="name.name == 'True'">POST</button></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```