# can we have ng-show and ng-if in one div tag?

Tags: angularjs, ng-show, angularjs-ng-if

Following code snippet does not work 
Please suggest any other way of doing it

```
<html>
`<div id="tablediv" ng-model="ngtable">
<div ng-show="ngtable">
<div ng-if="currentdevicetype == 'condition1'">
<!-- Other code to display contents -->
</div>`
</div>
</div>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes you can have.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, Both are different.

```
ng-show
```

sets the `display:none` of the element when expression evaluates to `false` while `ng-if` removes the element from the DOM when the expression evaluates to `false`

Answer (score 0):

**Check out this question to know the differences between ng-show and ng-if & where and How to use them:**

[When to favor ng-if vs. ng-show/ng-hide?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21869283/when-to-favor-ng-if-vs-ng-show-ng-hide)

Answer (score 0):

In your html code , you are using something wrong, because you are using `ng-model` for a div .

```
  <html>
    <div id="tablediv" ng-model="ngtable">
    <div ng-show="ngtable">
    <div ng-if="currentdevicetype == 'condition1'">
    <!-- Other code to display contents -->
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
 </html>
```

ng-model is used to bind the value of any inputbox/textarea/select like tags, you can not bind any value like this:

```
<div id="tablediv" ng-model="ngtable">
```

if you remove this `ng-model` then your code would be like this:

```
        <html>
            <div id="tablediv">
            <div ng-show="ngtable">
            <div ng-if="currentdevicetype == 'condition1'">
            <!-- Other code to display contents -->
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
       </html>
```

Now, if `ngtable` have some value it means `ng-show=true` then

```
 <div ng-show=true>
            // all the elements are visible on the DOM.
 </div>
```

but , if if `ngtable` do not have any value it means `ng-show=false` then :

```
<div ng-show=false>
                // all the elements are not visible on the DOM.
     </div>
```

And inside this code:

```
<div ng-if="currentdevicetype == 'condition1'">
        <!-- Other code to display contents -->
</div>
```

if `ng-if="currentdevicetype == 'condition1'"` returns true then all the elements would be create, otherwise element will not be created.