# How to hide button in ng-repeat in AngularJS?

Tags: html, angularjs, mongodb

#### My View:

```
<div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4" ng-repeat="(id, object) in objects">
    <button type="primary" 
        ng-click="add(id)"  
        ng-hide="id.plz" style="color: cyan;">Add</button>
</div>
```

#### Controller JavaScript:

```
$scope.add = function(id){
   // some function;
   $scope.objects[id].plz = true;
}
```

Any idea why it won't work?

Comment: `id.plz` is not true.

Comment: `ng-hide` takes a parametar and evaluates the parameter to true or false so if `id.plz` is a string and has any value other than empty `ng-hide` will trigger

add your `objects` object so we understand better

Comment: We can't know why it's not working. You have to post the code that populates `objects`, to see why the value is false.

Comment: it trigers, but with clicked button, all other also change their status to hide.

Comment: @ashketchum check out my edited answer found your problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4" ng-repeat="(id, object) in objects">

<button type="primary" ng-hide="objects[id].plz" ng-click="add(id)"   style="color: cyan;" >Add</button>

<div>
```

here in `ng-hide="id.plz"`  id is the index so there is no `id.plz`

learn more about `ng-hide` and alternatives [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21869283/when-to-favor-ng-if-vs-ng-show-ng-hide)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the users question. He don't ask for a `$index` based hide logic. Also this very low quality while you have 2 `ngHide` directives inside your button. Upvoters explain yourself =)))

Comment: Major problem will be id starts from zero, and while $index marking starts from 1, So only one is used. Either object in objects, usage of $index, but when (id, object) in objects is used, we avoid $index

Comment: @ashketchum could you please explain  what  is your use case here. I thought you wanted to hide and show based on index  but it seems thats not the case

Comment: @lin I miss understood his requirement .. will edit the answer when  explains the requirement

Comment: There is a list of images with button, and on clicking any button. I want that particular button to hide. Every image has already been assigned id. Problem:- i have no idea how to hide particular button, or even pass button id something

Comment: I still not understand your requirements @ashketchum You want to hide the button by clicking it?

Comment: `ng-hide="objects[id].plz"`  try with this in your button ..see if it works @ashketchum

Comment: Yup, it worked, but one question i was using plz instead of object[id].plz in ng-hide. Why it didn't worked, since plz would become property of that id? Am i wrong.

Comment: @ashketchum added an easy answer. The button is going to be hidden when it was clicked. I don't know why you try to access `id.plz` for hide when you logic you want is: click button, than hide it.

Comment: the problem was you were using `id.plz` . Id is the index only thats not an object but the real object is objects `objects` id.plz will not work because  id is not an object and you can not add  property to a non object value. mark answer as accepted if this worked @ashketchum plz would not become a property of id

Comment: thanks, i understood my mistake, thanks @BOSS and lin

Answer (score 1):

If you want to conditionally hide your button in ng-repeat, use ng-hide, ng-show(if there is a chance that you will hide and show it later) or ng-if(if it's a one time hide of button).

ng-hide takes a boolean and shows/displays accordingly. In your case your ng-hide is always turned out to be true, so you are unable to hide. Just write the condition required in your ng-hide to hide your button

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the users question.

Comment: I thought i could give him some example to help him understand as he is a beginner in angular

Comment: @lin There is nothing wrong in it to down vote. I'm just trying to explain him how ng-hide works.

Answer (score 1):

Hide the button when its clicked like in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k9rr7bkk/):

#### View

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="user in data">
      {{ user.name}}
      <button ng-hide="hide[$index]" ng-click="add();hide[$index] = true;">
        Add
      </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### AngularJS application

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {

    $scope.add = function () {
      console.log('add');
    }

    $scope.data = [{
      name: 'frank'
    },{
      name: 'peter'
    },{
      name: 'melanie'
    },{
      name: 'sven'
    },{
      name: 'basti'
    },{
      name: 'edjuh'
    }];
});
```

Comment: @BOSS IMO if its that simple, its ok. I preffer to manage those things always inside the controller .

Comment: yeah  that good .. but might cause problem in big project but in small ones will work perfectly ... breaking design pattern does not seem to heart unless in a team environment or big projects

Comment: @BOSS It doesnt, E2E binding is a AngularJS feature. Thats why we use AngularJS =). Its just not a good way to put the logic part into your view. But in this case it works very well and its a KISS solution.

Comment: @ashketchum Glad to help ya. You may going to mark the right answer (the grey tick near the upvote button). Also check your other questions and mark the right answer please.

Comment: I need 15 reputation, but surely will do once i am able to

Comment: @ashketchum Upvoted ya. =) now you should be able to mark & upvote now. Please also check your other questions.