# Performance about ng-show vs. ng-hide

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-ng-show

### Introduction:-

Some people are only using `ng-show` instead of `ng-hide="!true"` Or some peoples are using `ng-hide` instead of `ng-show="!true"`. Technically we don't need `ng-hide` directive. But! I know angular introduced `ng-hide` for  standard coding structure. And ***please understand me, I am asking about the performance not [difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21869283/when-to-favor-ng-if-vs-ng-show-ng-hide).***

### My Question:-

> So my question is  what about the performance of this following scenarios?

- `ng-hide="true"` vs.  `ng-show ="!true"`
- `ng-show="true"` vs. `ng-hide="!true";`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No different performance between `ng-hide` vs `ng-show`. It just uses CSS to show/hide the element.

```
<div ng-hide="true"></div> // => display: none !important;

<div ng-hide="!true"></div> // => display: block !important;
```

Similar for `ng-show`:

```
<div ng-show="true"></div> // => display: block !important;

<div ng-show="!true"></div> // => display: none !important;
```

You should compare `ng-show` (show element use CSS) vs `ng-if` (add element to DOM) about performance.

Comment: **You should compare ng-show vs ng-if about performance.** I know it.

Comment: Yes, I just add more details. I answered your question above.

Comment: Yes, I am sure.

Comment: Is `ng-hide` is needed?

Comment: It helps you no need use unless conditional :D