# AngularJS - Use ng-show directive

Tags: angularjs, ng-show

Attempting to hide the img using the ng-show directive.
[Code shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6XtBQ.png)

No hiding, even with false condition.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When to favor ng-if vs. ng-show/ng-hide?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21869283/when-to-favor-ng-if-vs-ng-show-ng-hide)

Comment: I think you want `ng-if` here.  Voting to close as duplicate.

Comment: Its better to avoid using ng-show, it has issues with IE. Use ng-if instead.
and what is the browser you are using?

Comment: I replaced ng-show with ng-if as shown: <img ng-if="false" width="300" alt="Angular Logo". Still no change.

Comment: I'm using chrome

Comment: You got the problem what you were doing?
you were using angular1, ng-if in angular2 :P

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
[hidded]="true"
```

or

```
*ngIf="false"
```

Comment: He is using angular1 not angular2.

Comment: But the code seems to be of Angular2 with typescript file. Sorry for the misconception.

Comment: Are you able to clarify why *ngIf="false" works and not ng-if = "false"? Is there a reference of the 'correct' formatting of directives that I seem to be missing?

Comment: I'm confused why references such as https://www.w3schools.com/angular/ng_ng-if.asp state it should be formatted as 'ng-if', but only '*ngIf' works?

Comment: @NathanDevery Please refer this:  https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf    , http://jilles.me/ng-click-and-ng-if-in-angular2/

Comment: Sorry my bad,  Shiha Mohan. He indeed is using Angular2.
You got the problem what you were doing? you were using angular1, ng-if in angular2 :P