# How to hide angular dropdown menu on a click

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I have a dropdown menu that closes if something is selected but stays open if nothing is selected. I am trying to do it so that it closes when the fa fa-caret-down arrow is clicked but it is not doing the trick. How can I fix it? Here is the code for that part:

```html
  
<label  style="color:white;">How many players?</label>
<div ng-class="{true:'error-bron', false:'nonerror-bron'}[dropDownPeopleError===true]" class="dropdown" ng-click="test()">
   <span>{{dropDownPeople}}</span>
   <i class="fa fa-caret-down bron-caret" aria-hidden="true" ng-click="test(); $event.stopPropagation();"></i>
   <div class="dropdown-content" ng-show="form.showDropDownPeople">
      <a ng-repeat="item in people" ng-click="changePeople(item); $event.stopPropagation();">{{item}}</a>
   </div>
</div>
```

And here is the part of my controller

```
$scope.test = function(){
    $scope.form.showDropDownPeople  = true;
}
```

Comment: I think you're going to want to do a function that is called onclick when the arrow is clicked that does $scope.form.showDropDownPeople  = false;  You could also do an onclick that changes the style attribute of the dropdown contents to display:none;

Comment: I wrote a function and placed it by the click but it is not closing the items by clicking the arrow:
<i class="fa fa-caret-down bron-caret" ng-click="hideDropdown();" ></i>

$scope.hideDropdown = function(){
        $scope.form.showDropDownPeople = false;
    }

Comment: Because you need to use onclick()

Comment: onclick broke the code. all divs became scattered around

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the element using `ng-show`, where the element only shows if the expression inside the tag is true, ie `ng-show="showDropDownPeople"`

Comment: Can you explain it a bit?

Comment: Angular has their own HTML tags which let you control how and when elements are shown. For example, you have `ng-hide`, `ng-show`, and `ng-if`, all of which let you define an expression to evaluate using your model (ie, your scope). See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21869283/when-to-favor-ng-if-vs-ng-show-ng-hide for more details. In your case, you can use your boolean value as the expression to control which elements show. But, I'm not 100% sure, so ymmv.

Comment: For example like adding the ng-click to the button?
<i class="fa fa-caret-down bron-caret" aria-hidden="true" ng-click="showDropDownPeople=true" ></i> Because this didnt work still