# ngShow if interpolated substring equals some substring

Tags: angularjs, substring, ng-show

I have the following `title`, and I want to `show` an `element` `if person == some value, e.g family`. How can I build that `expression` with `ngShow`?

`<h2 class="mat-title" style="text-align:center;">Register as a {{person}}</h2>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ng-if

```
<h2 ng-if="person==='family'" class="mat-title" style="text-align:center;">Register as a {{person}}</h2>
```

Comment: no you can but performance wise ng-if is better. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21869283/when-to-favor-ng-if-vs-ng-show-ng-hide

Comment: http://www.codelord.net/2015/07/28/angular-performance-ng-show-vs-ng-if/