# Angular JS - How to add extra DIV in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an array `a=[1,2,3,4,5,6]`.

Using `ng-repeat` on this array, I am creating 6 `divs`.

Please refer to this [**plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/fe4nTUFQ9ojEyBsyrOtH?p=preview)

Is there any way to add one more `div` after each row. So after 3 divs I want to add one extra `div`.

I looked into [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21351988/angular-js-ng-repeat-and-loop-conditions) example. but they are creating a child `div`. is it possible to create a sibling `div` in ng-repeat

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's try ng-repeat-start & ng-repeat-end.

```
<div class="example-animate-container">
  <div class="square" ng-repeat-start="friend in a">
   {{$index}}
  </div>
  <div ng-if="$index % 3 == 2" ng-repeat-end>
    extra div
  </div>
</div>
```

Please note that ng-repeat-start directive is included since angular 1.2.1.

[plnkr demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/IWCymJuCK5ShXtFGxX63?p=preview)

**ng-repeat:** repeat a series of elements of "one" parent element

```
<!--====repeater range=====-->
  <Any ng-repeat="friend in friends">
  </Any>
<!--====end of repeater range=====-->
```

**ng-repeat-start & ng-repeat-end:** using ng-repeat-start and ng-repeat-end to define the start point and end point of extended repeater range

```
<!--====repeater range start from here=====-->
<Any ng-repeat="friend in friends" ng-repeat-start> 
  {{friend.name}}
</Any><!-- ng-repeat element is not the end point of repeating range anymore-->

<!--Still in the repeater range-->
<h1>{{friend.name}}</h1>

<!--HTML tag with "ng-repeat-end" directive define the end point of range -->
<footer ng-repeat-end>
</footer>
<!--====end of repeater range=====-->
```

Comment: Can you please explain how `ng-repeat-start` and `ng-repear-end` works?

Comment: +1 for this one but I think your second example using `ng-repeat-start`is wrong. Where you have `<Any ng-repeat="friend in friends" ng-repeat-start>` should be `<Any ng-repeat-start="friend in friends">` instead. It didn't work for me otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

The `ng-repeat-start` and `ng-repeat-end` syntax was introduced for this exact purpose. See the documentation http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

So you'll do something like:

```
<div ng-init="a = [1,2,3,4,5,6]">

<div class="example-animate-container">
  <div class="square" ng-repeat-start="friend in a">
   {{$index}}
  </div>
  <div ng-repeat-end>Footer</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a empty div as a container for your repeat. And then only render the child element's as squares (or what ever you want). This way, your extra div will be a sibling and not a child.

See my example: http://plnkr.co/edit/xnPHbwIuSQ3TOKFgrMLS?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

take a look at this plunker here, could it be your solution? i don't understand really well your problem because i think it's better if instance your array in an external js file, but other than that take a look here [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/QAzOCsanZRpMpDofI2fV?p=preview)