# Angular JS - How to close and start DIV out of ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have one div as row and 4 div as column. I want to close row div after 4 cloumn div.

```
<div class="row">
<div class="clo"></div>
<div class="clo"></div>
<div class="clo"></div>
<div class="clo"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="clo"></div>
<div class="clo"></div>
<div class="clo"></div>
<div class="clo"></div>
</div>
```

Now in ng-repeart

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col" ng-repeat="x in values">
{{x.name}}
</div>
<div ng-if="$index % 4==0">
<div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
</div>
```

it's not working for me
I also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22907982/angular-js-how-to-add-extra-div-in-ng-repeat) as refrence but it only add clearfix div only. Not close the `div class="row">` and not start again `div class="row">`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The clearfix solution assumes you are using Bootstrap CSS. If you're not then you'll have to grab the clearfix class from Bootstrap.css.

If you are including Bootstrap, and looking to use Bootstrap to do the layout then you can use:

```
  <div ng-init="a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]">  <!-- sample data !-->

    <div class="row">
      <div ng-repeat="product in a">
        <div class="clearfix" ng-if="$index % 4 == 0"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
          <h2>{{a[$index]}}</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
```

Here's the demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/ibRsIfazxea2KpGmUg42?p=preview

Note I've reworked the answer from https://stackoverflow.com/a/32358013/1544886 to your requirements

Another option (based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/30259461/1544886)

```
<div ng-repeat="product in a" ng-if="$index % 4 == 0" class="row">
  <div class="clearfix" ng-if="$index % 4 == 0"></div>
  <div class="col-sm-3">{{a[$index]}}</div>
  <div class="col-sm-3" ng-if="a.length > ($index + 1)">{{a[$index + 1]}}</div>
  <div class="col-sm-3" ng-if="a.length > ($index + 2)">{{a[$index + 2]}}</div>
  <div class="col-sm-3" ng-if="a.length > ($index + 3)">{{a[$index + 3]}}</div>
</div>
```

You likely don't need the `clearfix` div, but as you have indicated in the comments that you want it as well, I have included it above.

Comment: `{{a[$index]}}` could be replaced with `{{product}}`

Comment: And if you prefer to do it exactly like you have in your example you can use this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/30259461/1544886

Comment: @K scandrett, Thanks for replying. But i try both solution and not getting exactly what i need, either clearfix div not come or row div not close after 4 col div

Comment: I can't able to attach image to show you what i got after following your example. Can you explain me where your row div close after 4 entries and again start.

Comment: I'm surprised the link in the comments didn't work for you. I've just updated my plnkr demo to include that method also.  Looking at the html it surrounds every group of 4 cols with a row div

Comment: If you want to post an image you could add it to your question

Comment: @K Scandrett, I try second mothod also but in this i can't see the clearfix div. row div fine in it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126783/discussion-between-k-scandrett-and-deepak3301086).

Answer (score 1):

Change it below like this: `$index` is available inside your `ng-repeat` and not outside.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col" ng-repeat="x in values">
        {{x.name}}
            <div ng-if="$index % 4==0" class="clearfix"></div>
        <div class="row">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```