# ng-repeat with an if-statement in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a website with a huge list of 30 **articles**. Until now this was like 300 lines of HTML code and with angularjs it is now like 10 lines. But some of these articles are special and so I need to be more specific what to show. Here is the HTML code:

```
<div id="illustratorcontent" ng-repeat="illustrator in illustrators">
        <article id="illustratorcontent{{illustrator.ID}}">
            <header>
                <h3>{{illustrator.name}}</h3>
            </header>
            <div class="illustratorcontentext">
                <p>This work is copyrighted and owned by {{illustrator.name}}...</p>
                <p>Details of the copyright holder: </p>
                <ul class="listplacing">
                    <li>Name: {{illustrator.name}}</li>
                    <li>Website: <a href="{{illustrator.website}}">{{illustrator.name}}'s website</a></li>
                    <li>Website: <a href="{{illustrator.website2url}}">{{illustrator.name}}'s {{illustrator.website2text}}</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </article>
</div>
```

and the IllustratorController is:

```
function Illustrator ($scope){
$scope.illustrators = [
    {
        "ID" : "Ilus1",
        "name" : "Ilus1",
        "website" : "http://Ilus1page.com/"
    },{
        "ID" : "Ilus2",
        "name" : "Ilus2",
        "website" : "http://Ilus2page.com/"
    }, ...
    {
        "ID" : "IlusX",
        "name" : "IlusX",
        "website" : "http://IlusXpage.com/"
        "website2text" : "Twitter IlusX",
        "website2url" : "http://twitterilusx.com/"
    }
]
}
```

So my question is how can I show the existing information and leave the **li** out where no info is given.

So on this line:

```
<li>Website: <a href="{{illustrator.website2url}}">{{illustrator.name}}'s {{illustrator.website2text}}</a></li>
```

how can I say that this line is just shown when the object parameter is given or not empty. I already looked for some ways. There is something called **ng-if** and **ng-ui** but that did not work out for me. Also there is a way to realize it with classes and hiding divs. But actually I would prefer to not generate them. And the **website2url**/**website2text** is just an example, there are more values than this.

Similar questions, but mine is a bit more special I believe:

- [angular ng-repeat with condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18056241/angular-ng-repeat-with-condition)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28334600/paginating-angular-ng-repeat-with-nested-filtering

Comment: Can you explain how ng-if didn't work for you?

Comment: Can you add code in jsfiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello create filter for to show the link of not like

```
<li ng-if="showSecondWebLink(illustrator)">....</li>
```

create function in your controller

```
$scope.showSecondWebLink = function(illustrator){
    if(illustrator.website2url && illustrator.website2text ){
       return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Actually I like the way of putting those logic into the controller. I fixed the small issue in your code. Thanks.

Comment: Can you please tell me what's wrong in code so i will update.

Comment: Well Someone deleted my change... I just deleted the **!= ''** then it works.

Answer (score 1):

Just try with:

```
<li ng-if="illustrator.website2url && illustrator.website2text">...</li>
```

Comment: I just tried it this way ```ng-if="illustrator.website2url != ''"```. That was too easy, thank you my friend, it's working properly.

Comment: @kwoxer, `null != ''`