# Using Or Condition in ng-repeat statement

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

How can I use a Or condition in ng-repeat. I currently have

```
<div ng-repeat="waterSample in viewRequest.data.REV_SAMPLE_CMQREQUEST_WATER_SAMPLE">
```

It can be viewRequest.data.REV_SAMPLE_CMQREQUEST sometimes. It should look for `viewRequest.data.REV_SAMPLE_CMQREQUEST_WATER_SAMPLE or viewRequest.data.REV_SAMPLE_CMQREQUEST` How can I solve this

Comment: What's the condition that you use to decide whether to show one versus the other? Is it simply a matter of one property being empty/false/null, while the other propertry will actually have a value?

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18056241/angular-ng-repeat-with-condition

Comment: @YellowShark I need to check if viewRequest.data has REV_SAMPLE_CMQREQUEST_WATER_SAMPLE  then iterate over it otherwise the other

Comment: The proposed duplicate does not apply. The duplicate is about filtering a collection, not choosing between two collections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve expected result, use below ternary condition to check property use REV_SAMPLE_CMQREQUEST_WATER_SAMPLE in  viewRequest.data and use REV_SAMPLE_CMQREQUEST_WATER_SAMPLE or REV_SAMPLE_CMQREQUEST based on condition

```
     <div ng-repeat="waterSample in viewRequest.data.hasOwnProperty('REV_SAMPLE_CMQREQUEST_WATER_SAMPLE')? viewRequest.data.REV_SAMPLE_CMQREQUEST_WATER_SAMPLE : viewRequest.data.REV_SAMPLE_CMQREQUEST">
{{wareSample}}
      </div>
```

working code sample

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.viewRequest = {
    data: {
      REV_SAMPLE_CMQREQUEST_WATER_SAMPLE : [
        {id: 1, name: "test1"},
        {id: 2, name: "test2"}
      ],
      REV_SAMPLE_CMQREQUEST:[
        {id: 100, name: "ABC1"},
        {id: 200, name: "ABC2"}
      ]
    }
  }
  
  $scope.conditionalArr = $scope.viewRequest.data.hasOwnProperty('REV_SAMPLE_CMQREQUEST_WATER_SAMPLE')? $scope.viewRequest.data.REV_SAMPLE_CMQREQUEST_WATER_SAMPLE : $scope.viewRequest.data.REV_SAMPLE_CMQREQUEST
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl"> 

  <div ng-repeat="waterSample in viewRequest.data.hasOwnProperty('REV_SAMPLE_CMQREQUEST_WATER_SAMPLE')? viewRequest.data.REV_SAMPLE_CMQREQUEST_WATER_SAMPLE : viewRequest.data.REV_SAMPLE_CMQREQUEST">
    {{waterSample.id}} {{waterSample.name}}
  </div>

</div>



</body>
```

codepen - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/GVZRem?editors=1010

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to use `ng-show`, like so:

```
<div ng-show="viewRequest.data.REV_SAMPLE_CMQREQUEST_WATER_SAMPLE" 
    ng-repeat="waterSample in viewRequest.data.REV_SAMPLE_CMQREQUEST_WATER_SAMPLE">
<div ng-show="!viewRequest.data.REV_SAMPLE_CMQREQUEST_WATER_SAMPLE" 
    ng-repeat="waterSample in viewRequest.data.REV_SAMPLE_CMQREQUEST">
```

Answer (score 0):

I think easier and cleaner way would be to concatenate those 2 arrays in your controller and then use it in your ng-repeat.